# How to export databases through command line?

Tags: mysql, command-line

I have URL of phpMyAdmin, I have username and password. How can I export all those databases? Because phpMyAdmin crashes when I try to export them, so I want to try it through command line.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
mysqldump -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -hHOSTNAME USER_DATABASE > FILENAME.sql
```

Then import using:

```
mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -hHOSTNAME USER_DATABASE < FILENAME.sql
```

Comment: I am sorry, but how can I know hostname if I have only URL of my phpMyAdmin?

Comment: you can probably just omit -hHOSTNAME, since it'll most likely be localhost

Comment: Is there no way to SSH to the webserver (which probably has the DBserver on the same server) or find the address of the DBserver? Try to get it from your hosting or you're pretty much screwed.

Comment: The second statement is missing a DB name, -hHOSTNAME can be ommited(if its localhost), so the correct code would be: mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -hHOSTNAME USER_DATABASE < FILENAME.sql.

Comment: @ErikČerpnjak: Thanks for pointing that out - I had totally missed the DB. Edited the post!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help everyone who needs this :)

Comment: Is this a mistake or do we really have to write it like `-uUSERNAME` e.g. `-uHans` or do we have to write ...... `-u Hans` ? I tried it like this `mysqldump -uroot -proot -hlocalhost magento_live > magentLiveDump.sql;` and it does not work, I get ` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use`

Answer (score 15):

`mysqldump -u user -p db_name > db_file.sql`

Edit: based on the comments on another answer.

If MySQL server allows for remote connections, then you can run this command on another machine you do have access to.

`mysqldump -h hostname-of-your-server -u user -p db_name > db_file.sql`

Answer (score 1):

As i was logged into my server already there i just had to put this command to dump db

```
 mysqldump --databases  database_name > file_name.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export all databases at a single command at the same time, use the following command instead.

```
mysqldump -u <THE USERNAME> -p --all-databases > all_databases.sql
```