# How to create dump of a single database?

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I am using wampserver 64 bit. I started the MySQL console via the wamp tray menu icon and executed this command as seen in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html).

```
mysqldump magento_live > dump.sql;
```

**Result:**

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'mysqldump magento_live > dump.sql' at line 1

I also tried it like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217578/how-to-export-databases-through-command-line):

```
mysqldump -u root -p root -h localhost magento_live > magentoLiveDump.sql;
```

**Result:**

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u root -p root -h localhost
>   magento_live > magentoLiveDump.sql' at line 1

I am using MySQL 5.7

---

I tried it via CMD by using this command:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.21\bin>C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.21\bin\mysql.exe mysqldump magento_live > test.sql
```

A file is created, but this is the content:

> C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.21\bin\mysql.exe  Ver 14.14 Distrib
>   5.7.21, for Win64 (x86_64) Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
>   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
>
> Usage: C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.21\bin\mysql.exe [OPTIONS]
>   [database]   -?, --help          Display this help and exit.   -I,
>   --help          Synonym for -?   --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
>                         'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
>                         and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
>                         --disable-auto-rehash.
>                         (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)   -A, --no-auto-rehash

[...]

Comment: Linux or window ?

Comment: I am using wamp, so yeah. Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `mysqldump` will not run from MySQL CLI, you will have to run it from the windows command prompt (CMD) or from the Powershell.

You have to start a CMD or Powershell and navigate to the bin folder inside the MySQL directory (*wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.21\bin*).

Then you have to execute the command like this:

```
mysqldump -u[USERNAME] -p target_database > target_dump_name.sql
```

**Important**: There is no space allowed between the option and the value.

**WRONG**:    `mysqldump -u root -p target_database > target_dump_name.sql`

**CORRECT**:    `mysqldump -uroot -p target_database > target_dump_name.sql`

---

### Example

**CMD:**

```
mysqldump -uroot -p magento_live > magento_live_dump.sql
```

**Powershell:**

```
.\mysqldump -uroot -p magento_live > magento_live_dump.sql
```

**Note**: In Powershell you will have to add `.\` before the command.

Comment: What is the use of the MySQL CLI then?

Comment: go to the mysql installation folder -> bin folder -> and run cmd . then type your command . you should be in the bin folder under the MySQL folder. @Black

Comment: I had to enter pass password and username by using the -p and -u options, but then it worked :)